# Can any one explain scope of c-macro's defined local to function and global?

Tags: c

I don't know why this output appears and behavior of pre-processor.

Output:

```
the value in main 10
the value in fun 20
the value in 2 main 10
```

Source

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int fun(int a);

int main()
{
    int a;
    a=MAX;
    printf("the value in main =%d\n",a);
    fun(a);
    int b;
    b=MAX;
    printf("the value in 2 main =%d\n",b);    /*<----doubt at this line*/
}
```

What's happening when we assign new value to the macro inside local function why it is not updating outside of function?

```
int fun(int a)
{
#undef MAX
#define MAX 20
    a=MAX;
    printf("the value in 2 main =%d\n",a);
}
```

Comment: Is this all in one file? What is the order of main and fun in the file?

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. You might want to read what macros are and how the **pre**processors works. Hint: it has no concept of _scope_.

Comment: yes everything in single file only in main() i'm calling fun().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro is not checked at runtime. It is checked during before compilation, in a stage called pre-processing.

So, the compiler processes the `main` function first and replaces `MAX` with 10 in all lines. Then when it reaches the `fun` function, it undefines `MAX` and redefines it with 20, and replaces the lines in `fun` with 20.

Comment: ...and uses the value `20` for `MAX` in all subsequent lines of the compilation unit.

Comment: but in function i'm changing the value of MAX. why it is not reflection in main after redefining in function? the max value replaces with new value wright?

Comment: As I said, the macro is not replaced at runtime. That means that it does not follow program execution, but the order that the macros are defined in the file. To see this, you can write the `fun` function above the main, but below the `#define MAX 10`.  In that case, all the printf statements will have value 20.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, you have written the code for the **fun** function after the **main** one.

The compiler changes the defined macros for its corresponding values in the order it find them in the source code, not in the execution order.